# What is the correct way to enforce unique "IS-A" relationship?

Tags: database-design, subtypes

Let's say we have a *Person* relation, and with that *Employee* which IS-A *Person*,  *Manager*, which ISA *Person* as well.

What is the correct way to ensure that a *Manager* isn't an *Employee* and vice versa ?

I didn't know what to look for when asking the question, there most likely already exists an answer to that question.

```
Person (PK:personId, name, ...);
Manager(PK:#personId); -- A manager ISA person
Employee(PK:#personId); -- An employee ISA person

INSERT INTO Person (1,'Peter',...);
INSERT INTO Manager (1); -- OK
INSERT INTO Employee(1); -- Nope, error.
```

> Person cannot be at the same time an employee and a manager.

Maybe with another example.

```
Shape (shapeId);
Rectangle(shapeId, width, length);
Circle(shapeId, radius);
```

Circle is a shape, Rectangle is a shape, how do I ensure Rectangle is not a Circle (and vice versa)?

Hence my question, What is the correct way to enforce unique "IS-A" relationship?

Comment: An employee is not a person. A person can play the role of employee. They can play the role of a customer, at the same time, too.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan generaly, yes. But rarely in B2B. I just encounter this very problem quite often and wanted to formalize it logically. For instance, a transporter can be either a truck or a container, but not both, a user can be an web-admin xor a buisness-admin xor a customer. Or many tiny inconsequential examples, that are implemented on the software layer, that I would like to see enforced. Cf edits in my posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relation `Application` that refer to the `Person` and `Position` relations should have unique `personID` attribute and should have the single attribute `positionID` that can have one and only one value at once.

Answer (score 1):

## Confusion

You have two separate questions here which prevent this from being answered

- You have one question about relationships (IS-A).
- You have one question about constraints *"manager isn't an employee"*.

One of them is about modeling, the other integrity. That makes it difficult to answer

## Modeling

Any time you see IS-A with a (1:1) in the scope of an RDBMS, you should think simple foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   person_id  int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   -- stuff
);

CREATE TABLE manager (
   manager_id  int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   person_id   int REFERENCES person,
   -- stuff
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
   manager_id  int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   person_id   int REFERENCES person
   -- stuff
);
```

If you have multiple inheritance (M2M), you'd use a linking table.

## Integrity

> *"Manager isn't an Employee and vice versa"*

This can only be done if either

- The relationship is stored in one table
- The database implement `CHECK` constraints which support queries
- You use a `TRIGGER`

That's your only option. If the relationship is stored in one table.

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
  id_person  REFERENCES person,
  id_manager REFERENCES manager,
  UNIQUE ( greatest(id_person,id_manager), least(id_person,id_manager) )
);
```

And that should work.

## Other Issues

These very simple cases often face bigger problems in the real world, for instance n-hierarchy relationships. What if the manager has a manager. That process of a separate table for each can get really absurd fast.

You could just do this,

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  id_person     int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  id_superior   REFERENCES persons
  ; stuff
);
```

But in this case there is no easy way to ensure `id_person` and `id_superior` do not create cyclic relationships in the graph, so again you have to get more clever...

And that's why this kind of question requires more information.

Comment: What does this line do ? : `CREATE TABLE relationships (
  id_person  REFERENCES person,
  id_manager REFERENCES manager,
  UNIQUE ( greatest(id_person,id_manager), least(id_person,id_manager) )
);`

Comment: Stores the relationships. You drop the `employee` table and store them like that instead. The UNIQUE condition ensures no bob is the manager of joe, and joe the manager of bob.

Comment: Ok so that's what that unique does. But then, it does not answer my question, on how can I make sure to have a single "type" for a person.

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume if you want to enforce static type, then use an enum which adds two bytes on the row (almost nothing). But be careful in your wording because *types* and *relationships* are different notions in every aspect. Something is 1:1  it is said it "is a" but it can be "is a" **to more than one thing**.

Comment: So in this case, *type* is a proper name ?